# Accessibility automated testing?

Tags: automated-testing

I am Software Engineer in Test and I have been assigned to test the accessibility of a webpage. We already have manual QA's for this and I would like to ask the following.

1. What do I do as a S.E.T. in this topic?
2. Are there any frameworks that apply to this kind of testing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there are official [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) and [Section 508](https://www.google.com/search?q=section%20508&oq=section%20508&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60l2j0l2.2151j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) documents which you should consider researching and accepting as guidelines to follow in your accessibility testing.

There are lots of tools for accessibility test automation ranging from commercial services like [`tenon.io`](https://tenon.io/) (even though I think the API is open and free but rate-limited) to open-source and free tools like [`AccessSniff`](https://github.com/yargalot/AccessSniff), [`HTML_CodeSniffer`](https://github.com/squizlabs/HTML_CodeSniffer), [`axe`](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/) from Deque Labs and Google's [`lighthouse`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) to name a few.

There is also this list at w3.org, but not sure how up-to-date it is:

- [Web Accessibility Evaluation Tools List](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tools/)

If by any chance, you are using Protractor for test automation, AngularJS team built [an "accessibility" plugin for Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor-accessibility-plugin) which uses [Chrome Accessibility developer tools](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/accessibility-developer-tools) and integrates with some of the services mentioned above.